# Imported eye glasses twice one I can see through the other is opaque. Why?

Tags: 3d-view

In the same file on the same level in the same viewport, importing the same object (a pair of glasses, OBJ) one has transparency the other doesn't seem to be able to go transparent even tho the preview orb is transparent. I even changed the material to the lens that was transparent and that did work either.

I haven't edited any any nodes.

The viewport shading is set to material.

What should I pay attention to in order to make the lenses show transparent.

Comment: Could you post a .blend? More details in your question? Problems like this are hard to solve w/o a detailed question and .blend. You can use [this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to post a .blend.

Comment: I just discovered that the lenses are transparent it is just that the head, hair, eye balls behind them are set to not show through transparent layers as I can see other things place behind the glasses. So what setting allows objects to be visible through transparency?

Comment: Is the transparency using mask mode?

Comment: Not mask mode, Z Transparency

Comment: Please upload your .blend (and it would be good for you to add 4 more tags btw)

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1728" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1728/)

If you try to view through the lens you'll see the box but not the eyeball.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually just a viewport deficiency. If you switch to rendered view or render out a shot, all is well :)

Blender's viewport only *attempts* to make it look right...to see what's really happening, render it out.